# Intellij IDEA Quick Definition Lookup shows only one line

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Quick Definition Lookup (CTRL + Shift + i) only shows one line in Intellij IDEA.

I want to see it full like this

```
static final CameraPosition _kInitialPosition = const CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(-33.852, 151.211),
    zoom: 11.0,
  );
```

but it shows this

`static final CameraPosition _kInitialPosition = const CameraPosition(`

Is it a bug or is there any configuration that I can appy?

Here's my intellij version and build. I'm using it on Fedora 29.

[image: Intellij version]

Screenshot of the problem
[image: Screenshot of the problem]

**UPDATE**
I've raised an issue on [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37752)

**UPDATE 2**
It resolved.
[issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37752)

Comment: Can you tell which version of IntelliJ are you using?

Comment: I've added on the post

Comment: I just installed Dart plugin and it is not working for me as well. I mean if it is 1 liner - that's fine. If it is method or whatever - good. If it looks same like yours - not working. Possible bug here :)

Comment: Please raise an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues, with demo project, where the problem reproduce attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've raised an issue on Youtrack and the bug is resolved.

[issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37752)